# Colcon Build fails on newly created package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm starting my first ROS2 project.
I followed the tutorial to create a workspace: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace/
Then moved on to the tutorial to create my own package: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package/
At Step 2 of the "Create my own package"
-That is, to say I ran

```
source ~/ros2_foxy/install/setup.bash
mkdir -p jeri_ws/src
cd jeri_ws/src
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake jeri_base
cd ..
colcon build
```

(This passed no problem) But then I realized I wanted the skeleton of the "node" flag, so I found an answer
answers.ros.org/question/330109/ros2-workspace-clean/ saying to delete the folders created by ros2 pkg create and re-attempt. No problem.

```
cd ~/jeri_ws
rm -r build logs install
cd src
rm -r jeri_base
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake --node-name hello-world_node jeri_base
cd ..
colcon build
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):ngoing] [examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor:build 100% - 1min 32.0s] ...
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 227, in run_setup
    script_name)
RuntimeError: 'distutils.core.setup()' was never called -- perhaps 'setup.py' is not a Distutils setup script?
--- stderr: jeri_base                                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_core/executor/__init__.py", line 91, in __call__
    rc = await self.task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_core/task/__init__.py", line 93, in __call__
    return await task_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_ros/task/ament_python/build.py", line 51, in build
    setup_py_data = get_setup_data(self.context.pkg, env)
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_core/task/python/__init__.py", line 20, in get_setup_data
    return dict(pkg.metadata[key](env))
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_ros/package_identification/ros.py", line 130, in getter
    desc.path / 'setup.py', env=env)
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 242, in get_setup_information
    setup_py, env=env)
  File "/home/jetbot/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/colcon_python_setup_py/package_identification/python_setup_py.py", line 283, in _get_setup_information
    cwd=os.path.abspath(str(setup_py.parent)), check=True, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', "import sys;from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet;from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    'setup.py', script_args=('--dry-run',), stop_after='config');skip_keys = ('cmdclass', 'distclass', 'ext_modules', 'metadata');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith('_') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data['metadata'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in ('license_files', 'provides_extras')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode('utf-8'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 1.
---
Failed   <<< jeri_base [6.52s, exited with code 1]
Aborted  <<< turtlesim [5.80s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor [1min 32s]
Aborted  <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber [20.1s]

Summary: 14 packages finished [2min 20s]
  1 package failed: jeri_base
  3 packages aborted: examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber turtlesim
  1 package had stderr output: jeri_base
Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-c', "import sys;from setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers import SpecifierSet;from distutils.core import run_setup;dist = run_setup(    'setup.py', script_args=('--dry-run',), stop_after='config');skip_keys = ('cmdclass', 'distclass', 'ext_modules', 'metadata');data = {    key: value for key, value in dist.__dict__.items()     if (        not key.startswith('_') and         not callable(value) and         key not in skip_keys and         key not in dist.display_option_names    )};data['metadata'] = {    k: v for k, v in dist.metadata.__dict__.items()     if k not in ('license_files', 'provides_extras')};sys.stdout.buffer.write(repr(data).encode('utf-8'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I retried making a new directory in ~/, creating a new workspace with that and re-attempting everything and I keep getting failures. I went back to my original workspace and started following the tutorials step-by-step, downloading the examples/tutorials into my workspace so I could source their stuff and I don't understand why I can no longer create a basic package using the ros2 pkg create command and it fails to build.

If I've made it difficult to understand my directory structure, below is the first 3 levels of tree from my workspace

```
jetbot@jetson:~/jeri_ws$ tree -L 3
.
├── build
│   ├── COLCON_IGNORE
│   ├── (various examples directories)
│   ├── jeri_base
│   │   ├── colcon_build.rc
│   │   ├── colcon_command_prefix_setup_py.sh
│   │   └── colcon_command_prefix_setup_py.sh.env
│   └── turtlesim
│       ├── colcon_build.rc
│       └── colcon_command_prefix_build.sh
├── install
│   ├── ( lots of files, from all the examples )
├── LICENSE
├── log
│   ├── ... (lots of logs, filenames omitted)
├── readme_for_env_setup
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── examples
│   │   ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│   │   ├── rclcpp
│   │   ├── rclpy
│   │   └── README.md
│   ├── hardware_driver.py
│   ├── jeri_base
│   │   ├── jeri_base
│   │   ├── package.xml
│   │   ├── resource
│   │   ├── setup.cfg
│   │   ├── setup.py
│   │   └── test
│   ├── ros_tutorials
│   │   ├── roscpp_tutorials
│   │   ├── rospy_tutorials
│   │   ├── ros_tutorials
│   │   └── turtlesim
│   └── testing
│       ├── motor_driver_test.py
│       └── servo_test.py
└── urdf
    └── jeri.xacro
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368144/colcon-build-fails-on-newly-created-package/) by [ajtoth](https://answers.ros.org/users/52181/ajtoth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-12-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of installing from apt, I built from source, building in ~/ros2_foxy according to the tutorial https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Development-Setup/

I solved the problem: the tutorial specifies that you need to run commands in a new terminal. I skimmed over those instructions. When I deleted my workspace (rm) and ran every block in its own SSH session, it worked no problem.

---

Originally posted by [ajtoth](https://answers.ros.org/users/52181/ajtoth/) with karma: 26 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After also struggling with this, you won't believe the solution. It is the hyphen "-" in the package name. Change hello-world_node to hello_world_node, and it will work.

---

Originally posted by [omerts](https://answers.ros.org/users/97134/omerts/) with karma: 11 on 2022-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1